# Update field value to a single value for all entries - mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called people and a field called language.

I want to update "language" field value to "english" for all entries.

I ran

> db.people.update({}, { $set : { "language" : "english" }});

I'm getting this error

> E11000 duplicate key error index: country.people.$RK_INDEX  dup
>   key

Can anyone tell me the proper way to achieve this.

Regards
Isuru

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10112810/59352

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
db.people.update({}, {$set: {"language": "english"}}, false, true);
```

Where false is "upsert" and true is "multi" (allows updating multiple records).

Do you have a unique index on that field? (that's the only reason I can think of that would cause your error.) It probably shouldn't be a unique index, if it is.

Comment: I have used ensureIndex , db.people.ensureIndex({"language":1}) but I haven't use unique:true